# Highlight sites using ZScaler root certificate

Tags: ssl, google-chrome-extensions, tls

Is there an extension to Edge, Chrome or Firefox that easily lets me know that the site is using the ZScaler root certificate for the TLS connection? It is good to know which sites could be vulnerable to a man in the middle attack, since the purpose of ZScaler is to inspect the content of the traffic.

I know that I can inspect the certificate and its path, but I want something more easily visible.